# Non-blocking sockets

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, blocking, nonblocking

What's the best way to implement a non-blocking socket in Java?

Or is there such a thing? I have a program that communicates with a server through socket but I don't want the socket call to block/cause delay if there is a problem with the data/connection.

Answer (score 34):

**Java non-blocking sockets** were introduced in Java 2 Standard Edition 1.4. It allows net communication between applications using the socket without blocking the processes. But Teo, what is a non-blocking socket?, in which contexts can it be useful?, and how does it work? Okay young Padawan, let's answer these questions.

### What is a non-blocking socket?

A non-blocking socket allows I/O operations on a channel without blocking the processes using it. This means, we can use a single thread to handle multiple concurrent connections and gain *"asynchronous high-performance"* read/write operations (some people may not agreed with that).

Ok, **in which contexts can it be useful?**

Suppose you would like to implement a server accepting diverse client connections. Suppose, as well, that you would like the server to be able to process multiple requests simultaneously. Using the traditional way you have two choices to develop such a server:

a. Implement a multi-threaded server that manually handles a thread for each connection.
b. Using an external third-party module.

Both solutions work, but adopting the first one you have to develop the whole thread-management solution, with related concurrency and conflict troubles. The second solution makes the application dependent on a non-JDK external module and probably you have to adapt the library to your necessities. By means of the non-blocking socket, you can implement a non-blocking server without directly managing threads or resorting to external modules.

### How it works?

Before going into details, there are few terms that you need to understand:

- In NIO based implementations, instead of writing data onto output streams and reading data from input streams, we read and write data from *buffers*. A *buffer* can be defined as a temporary storage.
- *Channel* transports bulk of data into and out of *buffers*. Also, it can be viewed as an endpoint for communication.
- *Readiness Selection* is a concept that refers to *“the ability to choose a socket that will not block when data is read or written.”*

Java NIO has a class called `Selector` that allows a single thread to examine I/O events on multiple channels. How is this possible? Well, the `selector` can check the *"readiness"* of a channel for events such as a client attempting a connection, or a read/write operation. This is, each instance of `Selector` can monitor more **socket channels** and thus more connections. Now, when something happens on the channel (an event occurs), the `selector` informs the application to process **the request**. The `selector` does it by creating **event keys** (or selection keys), which are instances of the `SelectionKey` class. Each `key` holds information about **who is making the request** and **what type of the request is**, as shown in the Figure 1.

[image: Figure 1: Structure diagram] *Figure 1: Structure diagram*

### A basic implementation

A server implementation consists of an infinite loop in which the `selector` waits for events and creates the event keys. There are four possible types for a key:

- Acceptable: the associated client requests a connection.
- Connectable: the server accepted the connection.
- Readable: the server can read.
- Writeable: the server can write.

Usually `acceptable` keys are created on the server side. In fact, this kind of key simply informs the server that a client required a connection, then the server individuates the socket channel and associates this to the selector for read/write operations. After this, when the accepted client reads or writes something, the selector will create `readable` or `writeable` keys for that client..

Now you are ready to write the server in Java, following the proposed algorithm. The creation of the socket channel, the `selector`, and the socket-selector registration can be made in this way:

```java
final String HOSTNAME = "127.0.0.1";
final int PORT = 8511;

// This is how you open a ServerSocketChannel
serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
// You MUST configure as non-blocking or else you cannot register the serverChannel to the Selector.
serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);
// bind to the address that you will use to Serve.
serverChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(HOSTNAME, PORT));

// This is how you open a Selector
selector = Selector.open();
/*
* Here you are registering the serverSocketChannel to accept connection, thus the OP_ACCEPT.
* This means that you just told your selector that this channel will be used to accept connections.
* We can change this operation later to read/write, more on this later.
*/
serverChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
```

First we create an instance of `SocketChannel` with `ServerSocketChannel.open()` method. Next, `configureBlocking(false)` invocation sets this `channel` **as nonblocking**. The connection to the server is made by `serverChannel.socket().bind()` method. The `HOSTNAME` represents the IP address of the server, and `PORT` is the communication port. Finally, invoke `Selector.open()` method to create a `selector` instance and register it to the `channel` and registration type. In this example, the registration type is `OP_ACCEPT`, which means the selector merely reports that a client attempts a connection to the server. Other possible options are: `OP_CONNECT`, which will be used by the client; `OP_READ`; and `OP_WRITE`.

Now we need to handle this requests using an infinite loop. A simple way is the following:

```java
// Run the server as long as the thread is not interrupted.
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    /*
     * selector.select(TIMEOUT) is waiting for an OPERATION to be ready and is a blocking call.
     * For example, if a client connects right this second, then it will break from the select()
     * call and run the code below it. The TIMEOUT is not needed, but its just so it doesn't
     * block undefinable.
     */
    selector.select(TIMEOUT);

    /*
     * If we are here, it is because an operation happened (or the TIMEOUT expired).
     * We need to get the SelectionKeys from the selector to see what operations are available.
     * We use an iterator for this.
     */
    Iterator<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();

    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        SelectionKey key = keys.next();
        // remove the key so that we don't process this OPERATION again.
        keys.remove();

        // key could be invalid if for example, the client closed the connection.
        if (!key.isValid()) {
            continue;
        }
        /*
         * In the server, we start by listening to the OP_ACCEPT when we register with the Selector.
         * If the key from the keyset is Acceptable, then we must get ready to accept the client
         * connection and do something with it. Go read the comments in the accept method.
         */
        if (key.isAcceptable()) {
            System.out.println("Accepting connection");
            accept(key);
        }
        /*
         * If you already read the comments in the accept() method, then you know we changed
         * the OPERATION to OP_WRITE. This means that one of these keys in the iterator will return
         * a channel that is writable (key.isWritable()). The write() method will explain further.
         */
        if (key.isWritable()) {
            System.out.println("Writing...");
            write(key);
        }
        /*
         * If you already read the comments in the write method then you understand that we registered
         * the OPERATION OP_READ. That means that on the next Selector.select(), there is probably a key
         * that is ready to read (key.isReadable()). The read() method will explain further.
         */
        if (key.isReadable()) {
            System.out.println("Reading connection");
            read(key);
        }
    }
}
```

You can find [the implementation source here](https://github.com/teocci/NioSocketCodeSample/blob/master/src/com/github/teocci/nio/socket/nio/NonBlockingWRServer.java)

#### NOTE: Asynchronous Server

An alternative to the the Non-blocking implementation we can deploy an Asynchronous Server. For instance, you can use the `AsynchronousServerSocketChannel` class, which provides an asynchronous channel for stream-oriented listening sockets.

To use it, first execute its static `open()` method and then `bind()` it to a specific **port**. Next, you'll execute its `accept()` method, passing to it a class that implements the `CompletionHandler` interface. Most often, you'll find that handler created as an *anonymous inner class*.

From this `AsynchronousServerSocketChannel` object, you invoke `accept()` to tell it to start listening for connections, passing to it a custom `CompletionHandler` instance. When we invoke `accept()`, it returns immediately. Note that this is different from the traditional blocking approach; whereas the `accept()` method **blocked until a client connected to it**, the `AsynchronousServerSocketChannel` `accept()` method handles it for you.

Here you have an example:

```java
public class NioSocketServer
{
    public NioSocketServer()
    {
        try {
            // Create an AsynchronousServerSocketChannel that will listen on port 5000
            final AsynchronousServerSocketChannel listener = AsynchronousServerSocketChannel
                    .open()
                    .bind(new InetSocketAddress(5000));

            // Listen for a new request
            listener.accept(null, new CompletionHandler<AsynchronousSocketChannel, Void>()
            {
                @Override
                public void completed(AsynchronousSocketChannel ch, Void att)
                {
                    // Accept the next connection
                    listener.accept(null, this);

                    // Greet the client
                    ch.write(ByteBuffer.wrap("Hello, I am Echo Server 2020, let's have an engaging conversation!\n".getBytes()));

                    // Allocate a byte buffer (4K) to read from the client
                    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4096);
                    try {
                        // Read the first line
                        int bytesRead = ch.read(byteBuffer).get(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

                        boolean running = true;
                        while (bytesRead != -1 && running) {
                            System.out.println("bytes read: " + bytesRead);

                            // Make sure that we have data to read
                            if (byteBuffer.position() > 2) {
                                // Make the buffer ready to read
                                byteBuffer.flip();

                                // Convert the buffer into a line
                                byte[] lineBytes = new byte[bytesRead];
                                byteBuffer.get(lineBytes, 0, bytesRead);
                                String line = new String(lineBytes);

                                // Debug
                                System.out.println("Message: " + line);

                                // Echo back to the caller
                                ch.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(line.getBytes()));

                                // Make the buffer ready to write
                                byteBuffer.clear();

                                // Read the next line
                                bytesRead = ch.read(byteBuffer).get(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                            } else {
                                // An empty line signifies the end of the conversation in our protocol
                                running = false;
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                        // The user exceeded the 20 second timeout, so close the connection
                        ch.write(ByteBuffer.wrap("Good Bye\n".getBytes()));
                        System.out.println("Connection timed out, closing connection");
                    }

                    System.out.println("End of conversation");
                    try {
                        // Close the connection if we need to
                        if (ch.isOpen()) {
                            ch.close();
                        }
                    } catch (I/OException e1)
                    {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void failed(Throwable exc, Void att)
                {
                    ///...
                }
            });
        } catch (I/OException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        NioSocketServer server = new NioSocketServer();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You can find [the full code here](https://github.com/teocci/NioSocketCodeSample)

Comment: Ha! Never knew of the async version. Life just keeps getting interestingly easier.

Comment: Lots of errors and confusion here. You kleep saying the selector creates the event keys. It doesn't. It only updates them. `SelectionKeys` are created by `SelectableChannel.register()`. 'Usually acceptable keys are created on the server side' should read 'always'. 'First we create an instance of SocketChannel with ServerSocketChannel.open() method' is incorrect. `bind()` does not create a connection. `Selector.open()` does not perform a registration. Listening sockets are not 'stream-oriented'. The asynchronous code ignores the `Future` returned by the `write()` calls.

Comment: The second one creates a thread for every incoming connection. Just tested it by adding `System.out.println("New connection added to " + Thread.currentThread().getName());` to completed method.

Comment: And `accept()` does not tell the channel to start listening for connections. It's already doing that.

Comment: @Teocci how asynchronous handler could be used for implementing call to Modbus? Like here: [Modbus Pulse Coils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66230042/modbus-pulse-coils-with-spring-boot-project).

Comment: Why u don't use the [Modbus](https://github.com/digitalpetri/modbus) implementation for java it has already implemented a high-performance, non-blocking, zero-buffer-copying library.

Answer (score 9):

> What's the best way to implement a non-blocking socket in Java?

There is only one way. `SocketChannel.configureBlocking(false)`.

Note that several of these answers are incorrect. [SocketChannel.configureBlocking(false)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/spi/AbstractSelectableChannel.html#configureBlocking%28boolean%29) puts it into non-blocking mode. You don't need a `Selector` to do that. You only need a `Selector` to implement timeouts or *multiplexed* I/O with non-blocking sockets.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from using non blocking IO, you might find it is much simpler to have a writing thread for your connection.

Note: if you only need a few thousand connections, one to two threads per connection is simpler. If you have around ten thousand or more connections per server you need NIO with Selectors.

Comment: Easier, but not Scaleable. Too much Threads and your pc doessnt like you any more because of the overhead on resources the program is consuming. Still it all depends on your individual needs.

Comment: @JasperLankhorst true, the number of connections you can have is limited to a few thousand with 1/2 threads per connection. With Selectors you can have 10x or more.

Answer (score -1):

java.nio package provides *Selector* working much like as in C.

Answer (score -2):

I just wrote this code . It works well . This is an example of the Java NIO as mentioned in the above answers but here i post the code .

```
ServerSocketChannel ssc = null;
try {
    ssc = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    ssc.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
    ssc.configureBlocking(false);
    while (true) {
        SocketChannel sc = ssc.accept();
        if (sc == null) {
            // No connections came .
        } else {
            // You got a connection. Do something
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Unusable. This code will spin-loop while there are no connections. A sane version of this would use blocking mode or else a `Selector.`

Comment: I think this solution is very similar to the blocking approach, the idea of using a non-blocking approach is create a handler to handle the accept whenever that event occurs. When you use this while (true) to get the socket is like you are blocking the thread until a client connection occurs.

Comment: This would be improved by having a blocking server socket channel, and you can still have non blocking connections.

Comment: @Teocci It is like smoking the CPU instead of using a blocking operation. It is very poor practice indeed.